# Passing data to recycler adapter with getter and setter problem

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass a string from my Main.java class to my RecyclerAdapter with getter and setters but I can't get it to work. I have read through all kinds of suggestions here at StackOverflow but still, I can't it to work. I hope someone can help.

Main.java

```
private List<ProjectId> projectIdList;

protected void onStart() { 
    ProjectId projectId = new ProjectId();
    projectId.setProjectId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    projectIdList.add(projectId);
}
```

ProjectId.java

```
public class ProjectId {

public String projectId;

public String getProjectId() {
    return projectId;
}

public void setProjectId(String projectID) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}
}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ProjectId projectId;
    private String projectID;

    public ViewHolder(View view, Context ctx) {
        projectID = projectId.getProjectId();
    }


}
```

It is returning this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   Services.ProjectId.getProjectId()' on a null object reference

I know that I have a value from `dataSnapshot.getKey()`. Is this the right way to try to do this or is there any other way? I appreciate all help.

Comment: how are you setting the projectId ?

Comment: I don't see if you have initialized projectId anywhere

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: You are getting `NullPointerException` because you are using `projectId` in `ViewHolder` constructor without initializing it first.

It's very clear that you are creating an object of `ProjectId` in `onStart()` and then you are setting its project_id as  `setProjectId()` but you have not passed this object to the `Adapter/ViewHolder` class whatsoever.